# Berry curvature Weyl and Dirac points

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, magnetic-monopoles, graphene, weyl-semimetal

I understand that Berry curvature sinks and sources correspond to Weyl points. However, I'm curious about the identity of points exhibiting a Berry curvature spiral, highlighted by red circles in the figure below.

Could these be Dirac points? Is it possible to differentiate between Dirac and Weyl points based on the direction of the Berry curvature rotation? It's worth noting that these two spirals exhibit opposite rotation directions.

[image]